# Why don't I get $e$ when I solve $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, indeterminate-forms

If I were given $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$, and asked to solve, I would do so as follows:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$$
$$=(1 + \frac{1}{\infty})^\infty$$
$$=(1 + 0)^\infty$$
$$=1^\infty$$
$$=1$$

I'm aware that this limit is meant to equal to $e$, and so I ask:

> **why don't I get $e$ when I solve $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$?**

Comment: To say it briefly: $1^\infty\neq 1$

Comment: You can't just replace $n$ by $\infty$ and call it solving a limit.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, not $\lim_{x \to \infty}$.

Comment: @OliverBel I find this a good question on the beginner's level. Lots of students find this type of limit calculations confusing/valid. The up votes perhaps reflect the fact that OP is not the only one finding this situation confusing.

Comment: @OliverBel : maybe becaue the OP took the time to type his efforts in the question.

Comment: @OliverBel: I agree with Stefan Smith. Limits may be obvious to you, but they aren't to Sim, and his/her question makes it clear what he/she's tried and why he/she's confused.

Comment: Euler defined the number $\large{\rm e}$ such that $\displaystyle{\large{{\rm d}{\rm e}^{x} \over {\rm d}x} = {\rm e}^{x},\ \forall\ x}$. Use this definition to find the limit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main problem here is that you use $\infty $ as if it were a number, and then you just substitute $\infty $ for $n$ and 'compute'. But, since infinity is not a number, you can't just substitute it and the computation you make is meaningless.

I'm assuming from the way you ask the question that you already know how to derive the correct value and that you are just wondering what is wrong with your approach. So, you don't get $e$ when you compute the limit they way you did precisely because your computation is invalid since you treat infinity as a number.

This may be extra confusing since sometimes substituting $\infty $ does lead to the correct answer, but this should be regarded as a fluke. For instance, the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac {1}{n}$ is $0$, which is what you would get by substituting $\infty $. But this is just coincidence that a completely faulty line of argument using entirely wrong 'computations' leads to the correct answer. Unfortunately, often when teaching calculus such substitutions and manipulations with $\infty $ are glossed over, or worse even encouraged. It is good practice to never ever substitute $\infty $ and compute with it.

Comment: 5th word in the 6th line from the beginning should "the" instead of "they"

Answer (score 15):

Consider $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+{1\over n})^n.$$ This limit has the indeterminate form $1^\infty$. Let $y=(1+{1\over n})^n$. Taking the natural logarithm of both sides of the equation and simplifying using the rules of logarithms we obtain $\ln(y)=n\ln(1+{1\over n})$. The $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln(y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\ln(1+{1\over n})$$ which has the indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$. We can rewrite the right-hand side limit as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(y)={\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}={\ln(1+{1\over n})\over {1\over n}}}$$ which has the indeterminate form ${0\over 0}$. Using L'Hospital's Rule we see that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{{1\over (1+{1\over n})}\cdot {-1\over n^2}\over {-1\over n^2}}.$$ This simplifies to $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln(y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+{1\over n})=1.$$ So far we have computed the limit of $\ln(y)$, what we really want is the limit of $y$. We know that $y=e^{\ln(y)}$. So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+{1\over n})^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\ln(y)}=e^1=e.$$ Thus $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+{1\over n})^n=e.$$

Answer (score 11):

*Hint* : $1^\infty=(a^0)^\infty=a^{0\cdot\infty}=a^\text{Indeterminate}=\text{Indeterminate}$.

A more comprehensive list of such undetermined expressions can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: I would say that $1^\infty $ should be interpreted as $\lim _{n\to \infty }1^n$ (which is $1$) rather then as the indeterminate expression you came up with.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$ . And $\lim_{n\to\infty}0\cdot n=0$ . But obviously this is not the case here, since $1+\frac1n\neq1\iff$ $\frac1n\neq0$ .

Comment: The point is that the problem with OP's approach is not that $1^\infty $ is or is not $1$ (and I say, it is $1$). The problem is in the steps leading to the wrong conclusion that the limit OP is interested in is the same as $1^\infty$. The problem stems from substituting $\infty $ for $n$, a practice that should never be done.

Comment: But it isn't... Pretty much for the same reason for which $0\cdot\infty$ cannot be reduced to the above mentioned case either, but is considered indeterminate. For instance, $1^\infty$ can also be viewed as $\lim_{n\to1}n^\infty$ , which can be either $0$ or $\infty$ , depending on how $n$ approaches the value $1$ .

Comment: things like $\lim _{n\to \infty }n^\infty $ have no meaning at all. You seem to interpret the expression $1^\infty $ as the limit of something that tends to $1$ raised to the power of something that tends to $\infty $, and that of course is not uniquely defined. But a much more natural interpretation for $1^\infty $ is as the limit of $1$ raised to the power of something that tends to $\infty $, and that is simply $1$. Anyway, this is besides the point of OP's question, and is just a matter of how does one interpret $1^\infty $.

Comment: But that's the whole point: the limit only exists if its value is unique, and beyond one's subjective interpretation.

Comment: I've encountered this ‘unnatural’ interpretation when faced, for instance, with computing the value of the improper definite integral $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx$ , so it's not quite so abstract as you might be inclined to think.

Comment: The point is that the interpretation and/or value of $1^\infty $ is only one fragment of where OP erred. The initial reduction of the limit OP was computing to the expression $1^\infty $ is where the problems start. Substituting $\infty $ and playing with it as if it were a number is a practice that should never be done.

Comment: So you keep on saying, but *generally speaking*, that's not true. Take for instance $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]2=$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^\frac1n=2^\frac1\infty=2^0=1$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms) for further details.

Comment: @Lucian: Yes, sometimes playing with $\infty$ and pretending it's a number will result in a correct answer, okay, sure. But getting the right answer most of the time does not make your steps mathematically valid. The symbol $\infty$ is not a real number, period. (Also, improper integrals $\int_0^\infty$ and infinite sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ are _defined_ by limits: $\int_0^\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n$ and $\sum_1^\infty = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_1^N$.)

Comment: Just because something is ‘not a number’ does not mean that *all* its operations are undefined. I'm sorry.

Comment: You are free to extend any number system you want to include infinity, and then it's up to you to tell us exactly how your new number system behaves. In analysis it is convenient to sometime speak of the extended real numbers, that includes $\infty $, but never as a number system. The bottom line is that $\infty $ is not a number. It is not a real number, nor a complex number, nor any kind of number. Treating it as if it were a number is unjustified. The fact that sometimes when you do that you get correct results does not justify anything.

Comment: Look, Mr. Weiss, with all due respect, I didn't make these rules. If I'm wrong, then so are all math teachers I've ever known, and all math books I've ever read. Nor did I or anyone else ever imply that ‘infinity is a number’. A matrix or a set isn't exactly a number either, but that doesn't stop us from ‘multiplying’ them, for instance. Nor are all operations which contain infinity undefined, but only some of them, and this for very logical reasons.

Comment: @Lucian it is possible the books you encountered and/or the teachers who taught you are/were wrong. I don't know unless you point me to a book or teacher and then I can form a better opinion about the book or teacher. Aside, not everything that can be multiplied qualifies as a number system. Numbers are different than matrices or sets. Now, you say you 'didn't make these rules' and this is precisely the problem. Which rules are you referring to? How are you to manipulate this $\infty$ (be it a number or not)? which laws does it obey?

Comment: Yes. It is, of course, “possible”.. :-) It's just not very *likely*, that's all.. :-) The undefined operations are the “negative” ones (- , $\div$ , log , $\sqrt{\ }$) that involve infinity on both sides, and the ones that can be reduced to them. This comes from the fact that $\infty\oplus(x>0)=\infty$ for all “positive” operations (+ , $\times$ , $\uparrow$, etc). For instance, $\frac00$ and $0\cdot\infty$ can both be shown to be equivalent with each other and with $\frac\infty\infty$ ; $1^\infty$ implies the former ; $\infty^0$ is the same as $\sqrt[\infty]\infty$ , and $0^0$ is its inverse.

Comment: I've found an easier way to remember it as $\log(1^\infty) = \infty\log(1) = \infty 0$ (if it were determinate, then taking the log would preserve this).

Comment: @lucian notice that you just specified more cases where manipulations with $\infty$ are meaningless (you even claimed two such meaningless things are equivalent, whatever that may mean) than cases where such manipulations are meaningful. This only serves to show why we don't regard $\infty $ as a number. When you find yourself introducing something but then immediately giving a whole list of exceptions, one must wonder if it's useful at all. Most mathematician's seem to agree (and I certainly do) that $\infty$ should not be computed with as a number (but rather as the top element in a lattice)

Comment: You lost me at lattice... :-) I also fail to understand your objection: the cases where operating with infinity is (quote/unquote) meaningful are infinite in number (e.g., $\pm\infty\pm x=\pm\infty$ , $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and there are an infinity of real or complex numbers, of course. The same goes for $\frac x{\pm\infty}=0$, etc). You are the first and only person I've ever heard say such things. (Are these your own original / personal opinions, or perhaps that of a [sizeable] minority? Or is it the accepted / official / orthodox teaching in your country or insitution ?)

Comment: The reference to lattices, without getting technical, is basically saying that you can add $\infty$ as a symbol to the real numbers and define it as the largest element. The only operations then that make sense are $x+\infty=\infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $x\cdot \infty=\infty$ for all $x>0$, and a few more. This is very rigorous and accepted and whoever uses it knows that this is a lattice theoretic concept, not a number theoretic one. What I'm objecting to is the practice, prevalent in many countries, of *computing* limits by substituting infinity. OP's question shows it is confusing.

Comment: as for whether or not I'm in the minority, certainly among practicing mathematicians I am in the majority (I challenge you to show me a research article or advanced textbook that has in it expressions like $1^\infty$ or the like). When it comes to teaching, most analysis courses will do a proper job but most calculus courses probably resort to the sloppy $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ business. When I teach calculus I tell all my students that any such computation will give them zero points immediately, they are not allowed to use $\infty$ that way in my classes, which may be more or less appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. (My father knows these things better than me). But aren't these two identities equivalent to saying $\infty-\infty=x$ and $\frac\infty\infty=x$ , and therefore undetermined, since that x can be anything ? This seems to be the logical conclusion. Then, by abstract or symbolic manipulation, the rest of undefined / undecided / undetermined relations follow. And then, with these logically-deduced exceptions in place, the ‘sloppy’ system becomes coherent, self-consistent, and self-contained. In other words, rigorous.

Comment: Such use of symbol $\infty$ only adds to more confusion. I have to agree with the viewpoint of Ittay Weiss.

Comment: Perhaps the following sums up my objection. The computation of, e.g., $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$ by substituting $x=2$ is an application of the theorem: if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $\lim _{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. However, the computation $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ by substituting $x=\infty$ is not an application of said theorem, nor of any theorem in fact. It is a mnemonic for the theorem: if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is bounded, then $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$. But, it is a bad mnemonic since it resembles something it is not, and so is confusing

Comment: @IttayWeiss: The slogan that $1^\infty$ is indeterminate is widely used in calculus textbooks. I use it myself when teaching calculus. It is short for the statement that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)^{g(x)}$ is indeterminate if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip this long discussion is evidence for the confusion that using certain mnemonics can create. Treating the symbol $1$ for anything other than the number $1$ (in this context of real analysis) is confusing. $1$ does not stand for "any function whose limit is $1$". Using the mnemonic "$1^\infty $ is indeterminate", while widely used, created confusion. Particularly in calculus courses, where often students substitute an understanding of what limits are in favor of a long list of tricks of how to compute limits, it is dangerous to reinforce this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

$1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form: the base is going to 1 which is trying to bring the expression to 1, but the exponent is going to $\infty$ which is trying to pull the expression off to $\infty$ as well.  That there are these opposing forces is how I try to explain why some forms of limits are indeterminate but other forms (like $0^{\infty}=0$) aren't.

Comment: In the expression $1^\infty $, the base is fixed.

Comment: @IttayWeiss But then how do you interpret $0^0$? Shouldn't both also be fixed?

Comment: $0^0$ is simply undefined. And the expression $1^\infty $ is something that is open for interpretation since the use of $\infty$ implies a limit. But in $0^0$ there is no limit implied and the answer is not uniquely determined by either the rules of algebra or the rules of common sense and applicability.

Comment: @IttayWeiss In most Calculus textbooks in North America, the convention is that any expression of the type $ \lim (f(x))^{g(x)} =a^b$ simply means that $\lim f(x)=a$ and $\lim g(x)=b$. Now, if $a^b$ makes sense as a number, the continuity of $x^y$ implies that this expression, understood in this conventional sense, is the same as the number $a^b$...... Note that $1^\infty$ makes sense with this convention, but it doesn't make sense in the standard sense..... Of course people not familiar with this convention might find other meanings for it, whcih could look or be more natural.....

Comment: @IttayWeiss ... but IMO it is improbable for a student to start using notations like $1^\infty$ without seeing this convention, which is pretty standard in some places, before....

Comment: Since $\infty $ is not a number, expressions such as $1^\infty $ are vague expressions at best and should be avoided. I am aware of the practice, especially in calculus classes, to pretend that $\infty$ is a number and use all sorts of half-baked conventions. This is a bad practice.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Remembering that $1^\infty$ is indeterminate is much easier than remembering that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)^{g(x)}$ is indeterminate if $\lim_{x\to x}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=\infty$. It's a mnemonic for remembering not an algebraic expression. It's similar to how we say $\infty/\infty$ is indeterminate. It reminds us that if the numerator and denominator both limit to infinity, the the limit needs to be evaluated by some other means.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip if you like we can continue this in chat. We certainly don't need to run the discussion in two different answer threads...

Answer (score 4):

I think it's instructive to look at what happens as n grows. At the bottom of my answer I've attached a plot showing $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ as a function of n from 1 to 100.

Hopefully this plot makes a little intuitive sense. Although as $n\to\infty$, $(1 + \frac{1}{n})$ gets very small, you are raising it to a higher and higher power.

For example, when $n = 10$:

$$1 + \frac{1}{10} = 1.1$$

which is pretty close to $1$, but!

$$1.1^{10} \approx 2.6$$

[image: e as a limit]

To answer your question: You **cannot** substitute the limiting value in the expression and get the proper limit. As an example, consider

$$f(x) = \frac{(x^2 - 1)}{x-1}$$

If we try to take the limit as $x \to 1$ by simply substituting $x = 1$, we get

$$\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = \frac{1^2 - 1}{1 - 1} = \frac{0}{0}$$

whereas the true limit can be found by factoring the numerator:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1} = x + 1$$

so:

$$\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = 2$$

See the Wikipedia page on [limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: 1) you probably meant to say that $1+\frac{1}{n}$ gets very close to $1$, rather than say that it gets very small. 2) The example you give later is a bit problematic for the purposes of the question. The substitution you give fails because of the term $0/0$. But then you show the correct computation, where you can eventually substitute and get the right answer. The issue is that substitution to compute limits is a good technique, but while it may work (under the suitable conditions), it never applies to substituting $\infty$. $\infty $ is not a number.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, 1) Yes you are right; I just noticed that. 2) You raise a good point. I initially thought the major mistake was the substitution, but in fact it is a combination of the substitution and $\infty$. I guess the second example, although it doesn't clearly illuminate the poster's mistake, still goes to show that simple substitution does not always work. I think the method of plotting the result for increasing n is a very good way to visualize what is happening during the limiting process.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a fairly good intuitive way to think about the problem but, as you point out, it does lead to the wrong answer.  The mistake you're making is to use intuition instead of recognised theorems to manipulate limits.  Get a textbook (or website) on limits, look up the results, and check that your assertions about the manipulations follow from these theorems. 
Besides your wrong answer of 1, very similar reasoning to yours can be used to obtain the answer of $\infty$. This false reasoning would work as follows.  If $x > 1$, then $x^\infty = \infty$.  Since $1 + \frac{1}{n}$ is always we greater than $1$, the limit is $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^\infty = \infty$ 
Unsurprisingly, the actual answer of $e$ lies between these two wrong answers.  To actually solve your problem, evaluate the complete expression of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$.  Imagine that n is a large real number (like a million) and examine the expansion.  You should see that it is similar to the standard expression for $e$, and that should help you to prove formally that the expansion tends to $e$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Paul Epstein

Comment: Please use proper latex command to set up your answer.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Seriously? I've seen worse than that, the answer is perfectly readable as-is.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $1 + 1/n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, which would tend to make the limit close to or equal to $1$, but at the same time the exponent $n$ is approaching infinity, which would tend to make the limit very large.  It's not apparent which is more important, and whether the limit is $1$, $\infty$, some number in between, or maybe it doesn't exist at all.  It turns out that, roughly speaking, the convergence of $1 + 1/n$ to $1$ and the convergence of $n$ to $\infty$ are equally important, and the limit turns out to be something "in between", namely $e$.  Someone will probably post a complete proof that the limit is $e$, but that is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Noting : $(1+1/n)^n=e^{n \log(1+1/n)}$

And when $x\to 0$: $\log(1+x) = x+o(x)$

Or again $n \to \infty$: $log(1+1/n)=1/n+o(1/n)$

Scope : $(1+1/n)^n=e^{1+o(1)}$

Answer (score 0):

Answer: It is same thing to prove $(1+x)^{1/x}$ as $x$ goes to $0$ its limit is e.
Say $(1+x)^{1/x}=y$  then take log of both side. Then take limit as x approaches to 0 of both sides. Then Use L'Hopital. You will get exactly e.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb with these "determinate" and "indeterminate" forms is if you can think of a way to screw it up, i.e., get a different answer depending on how you look at it, it's indeterminant. For example, $\frac{0}{0}$, the classic indeterminate form, is broken by $1 = \frac{x}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$ as $x\to 0$ and $x=\frac{x^2}{x}$ goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$. So we can equally interpret $\frac{0}{0}$ as $1$ or as $0$.  Put another way, it really depends on how fast the numerator and denominator approach $0$ relative to one another.

The way to think of $1^\infty$ is this. $$x^\infty=\begin{cases}\infty,&\text{if }x > 1\\0,&\text{if }0 < x < 1\end{cases}$$ (more formally $\lim_{a\to\infty}x^a$ equals the right-hand side). So if you interpret $1^\infty$ using the first formula, you get $\infty$, and if you interpret in using the second, you get $0$. You can interpret it a third way as you saw as $1^a = 1$. What it boils down to is that $1^\infty$ really depends on how fast the base approaches one relative to how fast the exponent approaches $\infty$. You can get any number you want by varying the rate (or at least any nonnegative number), including $e$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{4n^2+2n+1}{4n^2}\right)^n>\left(\frac{4n^2+2n}{4n^2}\right)^n=\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n.$$

so that there is an increasing subsequence.

If the limit exists, it must exceed $2$ (and also $1.000000001^{1000000000}\approx2.7182818270999\cdots$).