# graphing $f(x)=x \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms

I was assigned to draw the graph of this function
$f(x)$=$x\ln(1+{1\over x})$.

When I calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$
I get $1$ but the teacher said it's not correct even though its graph on the internet shows that
$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$.

Please tell me where did I  go wrong?

Comment: Chose the wrong teacher.

Comment: You should show your teacher the graph of the function.

Comment: I think he said that $lim_{x\to\infty}$ $f(x)$=$0$

Comment: @user115947 your current problem is to find a tactful way to convey Andre Nicolas' comment to your teacher. Unfortuantely this site is about math, not tact.

Comment: It could be that one of you two confused $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$.

Comment: show him [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+ln%281%2B1%2Fx%29%2C+%7Bx%2C100%2C200000%7D ]

Comment: You could tell your teacher you are **confused** and then type something like 'x*ln(1+1/x) from 1 to 100000' in google or like what janmarqz does in WA. The trick is you should make yourself look really confused and begging him/her to save you. Of course, if you can change your teacher, then it will be even better.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\log (1+\frac{1}{x}) \sim \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x}$

EDIT: another way to see it is to use the definition of $e=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$:
$$
\lim_{s \to \infty}s \log \bigg(1+\frac{1}{s} \bigg)=\lim_{s \to \infty}\log \bigg(1+\frac{1}{s}\bigg)^{s}=\log \lim_{s \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{s} \bigg)^s=\log e^1=1
$$

Comment: (I think one writes $\lim(f/g)=1$ as $f\sim g$ not $\lim f\sim\lim g$.)

Comment: Yeah well I meant of course $f \sim g$ as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

First: You are right! The **limit** $1$ **is correct**! To prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 1$ you could use *L'Hôpital's rule*

It holds:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2+x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}} =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^2+x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 1- \frac{1}{x+1} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you know but for small values of $x$, we can use a Taylor expansion like so : $$\ln(1+y) \approx y + \frac{y^2}2 + ...$$

Now let $\frac1x = y$, when $x\to \infty$, you have $y\to 0$ therefore you can write the following : $$\ln(1+\frac1x) \approx \frac1x + \frac{1}{2x^2} + ...$$

So when you multiply by $x$ you get : $$x\ln(1+\frac1x) \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2x} + ...$$
Where $...$ are other power of $\frac1x$ wich all tend to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

It should give you a good idea to what the limit tends to although a little bit more work is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> *Too long for a comment:*

I think what happened is that your teacher forgot about the “$\ln$” and calculated $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$, since $a\ln b=\ln(a^b)$. Obviously, that limit is *e*, whose natural logarithm is of course $1$. Then, when s/he heard you saying the limit is $1$, s/he thought you were making the [common mistake](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550485/why-dont-i-get-e-when-i-solve-lim-n-to-infty1-frac1nn) of saying that $1^\infty=1$, when in fact it is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). In other words, I just think your teacher got confused.